# Regex search in python for angular project

Tags: python, angular, regex, search

Searching through one file:

```
import re

textfile = open("dummyData", 'r')
matches = []
reg = re.compile("\w+(?=\s?\|\s?maximum)")
for line in textfile:
    matches += reg.findall(line)
textfile.close()
print(matches)
```

Questions:

1. How can I search through whole angular project and have all matches in one array?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the whole project thing I think you are looking for a Multiline `re.M` flag when compiling. This changes the behavior of regex with regards to `\n` characters. You can do this with `textfile.read` function. As for question 2, please provide some indication of what the problem is. An example of what output is produced by the code and what is wrong with it would help.

Comment: Edited, could u write more about Multiline re.M flag?

Comment: To match `abc`, `adsa`, and `ppopop` in the above example you can use `\w+(?=\s?\|\s?maximum)` pattern. `\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `+` is one or more. Followed by a positive lookahead, `?=`, of zero or one space followed by `|` followed by zero or one space followed by `maximum`.

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you! How can i search by this through whole Angular project?

Comment: If you mean to search an entire file, instead of using `for line in textfile` use `textfile.read()` which will read all the text and then you can `findall` once to get everything.

Comment: I want to search through entire FrontEnd project so many files and folders as well

Comment: Use `os.walk` to walk the project directory and process the files one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```py
import re, glob

matches = []
reg = re.compile(r"\w+(?=\s?\|\s?maximum)")

files = [file for file in glob.glob("*dummyData*")]
for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            matches += reg.findall(line)

print(matches)
```